# How do particles described as wave function interact?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Let's suppose there are two electrons in a potential box. The Schrödinger's equation of a system includes a factor representing electric potential of their interaction. How is it computed? Do we have to integrate over a square of an amplitude of all the wave function values for one electron to get a potential it generates for another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can discuss this perfectly sensibly in non-relativistic many-particle QM. Suppose you have two particles with momenta $p_1, p_2$ and Hamiltonian:

$$ H = \frac{p_1^2}{2m_1} + \frac{p_2^2}{2m_2} + V(r_1,r_2) $$

for some interaction potential that is a function of $r_1,r_2$. Then you solve the Schroedinger equation exactly as always: you have some initial ket $|\psi(0)\rangle$ and you compute the final ket $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-i Ht}|\psi(0)\rangle$. Actually exponentiating that operator is generally difficult and requires you to be able to diagonalise it, but this is 'just' a matter of solving a differential equation (the Time Independent Schroedinger equation). The relevant TISE in position basis is:

$$ E = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m_1}\nabla_1^2+ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m_2}\nabla_2^2 + V(r_1,r_2)$$

which is not so different from the one particle cases you're used to where the TISE looks like:

$$ E = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(r) $$

Specific techniques to deal with this in the context of many particles (or an indefinite number in the case of relativistic particles) usually make use of methods from QFT, but for a fixed small number of particles the above is a complete description of the problem.

---

More specifically OP about how to think about the energy of the interaction. There's two things to note here:

1. The interaction energy is not a quantity you actually need to talk about to compute the time evolution. Nonetheless, you can consider the expectation $\langle \hat{V} \rangle$ and this is of course useful in certain contexts. For two particles this boils down the the integral:

$$\langle V \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\int dr_1 dr_2 \psi^*(r_1,r_2) V(r_1,r_2) \psi(r_1,r_2)$$

2. It doesn't make a huge amount of sense to talk about one particle feeling the potential of the other. If you have two electrons, then there is an interaction Hamiltonian that's easy to write down, and there is an expectation value of that that you can compute, but there's not necessarily a meaningful way to extract a single 'potential' from the first electron that is then felt by the second. This is only the case if the wavefunction is seperable $\psi(r_1,r_2)=\psi(r_1)\psi(r_2)$ so that:

\begin{align}
\langle V \rangle &= \frac{1}{2}\int dr_1 dr_2 \psi^*(r_1)\psi(r_1) V(r_1,r_2) \psi^*(r_2)\psi(r_2) \\
 & = \frac{1}{2}\int dr_1 \left(\int dr_2 \rho(r_2)V(r_1,r_2)\right) \rho(r_2)
\end{align}

then you might reasonably interpret the inner bracket as the classical potential generated at $r_1$ by the charge distribution $\rho(r_2)$.